# String interpolation in array assignement over SSH

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I'm trying to assign container names to an array.

The command works perfectly when I'm running it without assigning to an array:

```
ARR=docker network inspect --format '{{ range $key, $value := .Containers }}{{ printf "%s\n" $value.Name}}{{ end }}' some_network $$ echo $ARR
```

I'd like to do same thing but over SSH:

```
ssh root@68.183.74.135 "
ARR=( $(docker network inspect --format '"'{{ range $key, $value := .Containers }}{{ printf "%s\n" $value.Name}}{{ end }}'"' some_network) ) && echo $ARR
"
```

but it complains:

```
Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected unclosed action in command
```

I guess the reason lies in string interpolation or escaping `'`, can u give any advice guys?

Comment: `echo $ARR` is equivalent to `echo ${ARR[0]}`, you'll only see the first element.

Comment: But the problem is that you have the command substitution and  `echo $ARR` in a double-quoted string, so your local  shell will expand those _before_ launching ssh

Comment: Why are you assigning the ARR variable remotely? Do you want to manipulate the data on your machine or the remote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within double-quotes, the command substitution would be handled on the local end, and the local shell would parse the quoting inside.

If you want to run it on the remote, you need something like

```
ssh root@68.183.74.135 '
  ARR=( $(docker network inspect --format '\''{{ range $key, $value := .Containers }}{{ printf "%s\n" $value.Name}}{{ end }}'\'' some_network) ) && echo $ARR
'
```

or you could maybe avoid the quoting hell by giving the commands via stdin instead:

```
ssh root@68.183.74.135 <<'EOF'

ARR=( $(docker network inspect --format '{{ range $key, $value := .Containers }}{{ printf "%s\n" $value.Name}}{{ end }}' some_network) ) && echo $ARR
EOF
```

or by having the whole script in a separate file (on the remote or local side), and running from that.